# Screen capture is not working with ddms in Intel® Atom™ x86 Image for Android

Tags: android, adt, ddms, intel-atom

when I try to screen capture in Intel® Atom™ x86 Image for Android it doesn't worked in Ubuntu ! , I'm looking for a right solution, at least reason  , I tried with this `adb shell /system/bin/screencap -p /sdcard/img.png` command but it creates dummy Image of *0KB*.

[image]